# Compressing image before exporting in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to compress a GeoTIFF in Google Earth Engine before exporting it into, for example, the drive folder? I'm thinking about a functionality similar to GDAL's LZW compression.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, GEE exports raster files in two formats: GeoTiff and TFRecord.

There are some [optional parameters for each format](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/af7d1509f46502250e750b53bdd246ed0f4e7b96/python/ee/batch.py#L861):

GeoTiff: `'tiffCloudOptimized'`, `'tiffFileDimensions'`

TFRecord: `'tfrecordPatchDimensions'`, `'tfrecordKernelSize'`, `'tfrecordCompressed'`, `'tfrecordMaxFileSize'`, `'tfrecordDefaultValue'`, `'tfrecordTensorDepths'`, `'tfrecordSequenceData'`,`'tfrecordCollapseBands'`, `'tfrecordMaskedThreshold'`

There is no parameter related to compression.

If you want to reduce file size, convert your images to an integer value type sucha as `toInt8()`. If the image is float type (like NDVI or reflectance values between 0-1, or any other value with significant decimals), apply an scale factor like 1000 or 10000 and then convert the images. This will reduce image size